# Highlighting particular bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm trying to create a bibliography in which certain items are highlighted as being more important. Ideally this would put an asterisk at the front of that particular item while leaving the sorting unchanged. I'm using `biblatex-chicago` with Biber as the backend.

Say I have these two entries in my `.bib` file:

```
@article{cite1,
  author = {Knuth, Donald},
  title = {{Title One}},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  year = {2005},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1--42},
}

@book{cite2,
  author = {Knuth, Donald},
  title = {{A Way More Important Title}},
  publisher = {Oxford},
  year = {2009},
  address = {New York}
}
```

What I'd like to do is highlight the second one so that the sort order and repeated name dash stays unchanged. Ideally it would produce something like this:

---

Knuth, Donald. 2005. "Title One." *Some Journal* 1: 1-42.

*———. 2009. *A Way More Important Title*. Oxford: New York.

---

Is there some way to achieve this? Some additional key I could put in the important entries, perhaps? I've tried faking the name (like `name = {*Knuth, Donald}, sortname = {Knuth, Donald}`), but that breaks the 3-em dash replacement.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice the asterisk as the means for highlighting.  Is that the preferred output?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's an easy way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{cite1,
  author = {Knuth, Donald},
  title = {{Title One}},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  year = {2005},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1--42},
}

@book{cite2,
  author = {Knuth, Donald},
  title = {{A Way More Important Title}},
  publisher = {Oxford},
  year = {2009},
  address = {New York}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%% Highlight entries
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}
% the colour definition
\colorlet{impentry}{Maroon}% let 'impentry' = Maroon

% Inform biblatex that all books in the 'important' category deserve
% special treatment, while all others do not
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifcategory{important}%
    {\bfseries\color{impentry}}%
    {}%
  }

% Add books to 'important' category in preamble
\addtocategory{important}{%
 cite2,
}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

A trickier way would be to use `biber`'s `\DecareSourcemap` command (documented in `biblatex` manual) to essentially grep for a keyword in the `keywords` field and then act accordingly.  One advantage of this method is that it means the 'initialization' is put in the `.bib` file rather that needing to declare new bibliography categories and so on.  (You also get to re-write the bibliography output on the fly, so you could have only [say] an `addendum` field that is highlighted.)

There might also be reason to create other useful commands like an `\addncite`, which `\cite`s the entry and adds it at the same time to this new 'important' category.  Not sure what your overall needs are, however.

Comment: Beautiful. `\AtEveryBibitem` was what I needed. Adding things to categories works fine for what I need, and I was able to get an asterisk before with the command `\AtEveryBibitem{\ifcategory{important}{* }{}}`.

Comment: @user42659 -- Ah, OK.  Glad it works.

Comment: @jon I suspect it only works with biblatex, doesn't it ? Is biber strictly required ?

Comment: @VincentFourmond -- The answer explicitly relies on `biblatex` in this case, but Biber is not required. However, `\DeclareSourcemap` is a Biber-specific command.

Comment: @jon Thanks. I have been considering switching to biblatex for a while, this looks like yet another good argument to do so...

Answer (score 0):

I found the linked answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402765/how-do-i-mark-bibliography-entries-in-the-margin?rq=1) better than this solution because it allowed for entries to be marked with in the keyword field rather than listing the individual cite keys to be highlighted.