# How can I change the color of bibliography headers when I use biblatex with the reading style?

Tags: biblatex

Based on the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149753/4172 to the question [Highlighting particular bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149743/highlighting-particular-bibliography-entries/149753#149753), I am trying to obtain a reference listing using the reading style of biblatex, where some items are highlighted.

The code I've got is the following (which is the same as in the above-mentioned answer, with the exception that I am using the reading style for biblatex):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{cite1,
  author = {Knuth, Donald},
  title = {{Title One}},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  year = {2005},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1--42},
}

@book{cite2,
  author = {Knuth, Donald},
  title = {{A Way More Important Title}},
  publisher = {Oxford},
  year = {2009},
  address = {New York}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=reading]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%% Highlight entries
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}
% the colour definition
\colorlet{impentry}{Maroon}% let 'impentry' = Maroon

% Inform biblatex that all books in the 'important' category deserve
% special treatment, while all others do not
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifcategory{important}%
    {\bfseries\color{impentry}}%
    {}%
  }

% Add books to 'important' category in preamble
\addtocategory{important}{%
 cite2,
}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The result I am getting looks like the following:

[image]

How can I also change the color of the header of the first entry? That is, how can I highlight the text `Knuth: A Way More Important Title cite2`and the corresponding underline below it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "headers" are created using the bibmacro `entryhead:full` (or `entryhead:name`, depending on the value passed to `entryhead`).

In order to also colour in the entry head we just apply the code in `\AtEveryBibitem` to `entryhead:full`:

```
\renewbibmacro*{entryhead:full}{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\bfseries\color{impentry}}
    {}
  \printnames[labelname][-1]{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \printfield{labeltitle}}
```

This is analogous for `entryhead:name`:

```
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{entryhead:name}{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\bfseries\color{impentry}}
    {}
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{labeltitle}}
    {\printnames[labelname]{labelname}}%
  \savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother
```

If you want to keep the colouring more local (don't colour the entry key) we can do that with a bit of group action:

```
\renewbibmacro*{entryhead:full}{%
  \begingroup
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\bfseries\color{impentry}}
    {}
  \printnames[labelname][-1]{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \printfield{labeltitle}
  \endgroup}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=reading]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

%% Highlight entries
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}
% the colour definition
\colorlet{impentry}{Maroon}% let 'impentry' = Maroon

% Inform biblatex that all books in the 'important' category deserve
% special treatment, while all others do not
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifcategory{important}%
    {\bfseries\color{impentry}}%
    {}%
  }

% Add books to 'important' category in preamble
\addtocategory{important}{%
 cicero,
}

\renewbibmacro*{entryhead:full}{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\bfseries\color{impentry}}
    {}
  \printnames[labelname][-1]{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \printfield{labeltitle}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{wilde,cicero}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you also want to colour in the horizontal rule, it is probably better to modify another macro (that is, you do not have to apply the customisations to `entryhead:full` above)

```
\makeatletter
\def\bbx@item@full{%
  \begingroup
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\color{impentry}}
    {}
  \itemsep2\bibitemsep
  \@itempenalty\z@
  \item\relax
  \begingroup
  \samepage\bfseries
  \def\finentrypunct{\strut}%
  \usebibmacro{entryhead:full}%
  \ifbool{bbx:entrykey}
    {\def\newblockpunct{%
       \nobreak\hskip\z@skip\strut
       \hfill\penalty100\hskip1em\relax
       \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill\strut}%
     \def\finentrypunct{%
       \parfillskip\z@\finalhyphendemerits\z@
       \par\nobreak}%
     \newblock
     \printfield{entrykey}}
    {}%
  \finentry
  \endgroup
  \hrule height 1.25pt\relax
  \itemsep\bibitemsep
  \@itempenalty\@M
  \item\strut
  \@itempenalty\z@
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=reading]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

%% Highlight entries
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}
% the colour definition
\colorlet{impentry}{Maroon}% let 'impentry' = Maroon

% Inform biblatex that all books in the 'important' category deserve
% special treatment, while all others do not
%\AtEveryBibitem{%
%  \ifcategory{important}%
%    {\bfseries\color{impentry}}%
%    {}%
%  }

% Add books to 'important' category in preamble
\addtocategory{important}{%
 cicero,
}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifcategory{important}%
    {\bfseries\color{impentry}}%
    {}%
}

\makeatletter
\def\bbx@item@full{%
  \begingroup
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\color{impentry}}
    {}
  \itemsep2\bibitemsep
  \@itempenalty\z@
  \item\relax
  \begingroup
  \samepage\bfseries
  \def\finentrypunct{\strut}%
  \usebibmacro{entryhead:full}%
  \ifbool{bbx:entrykey}
    {\def\newblockpunct{%
       \nobreak\hskip\z@skip\strut
       \hfill\penalty100\hskip1em\relax
       \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill\strut}%
     \def\finentrypunct{%
       \parfillskip\z@\finalhyphendemerits\z@
       \par\nobreak}%
     \newblock
     \printfield{entrykey}}
    {}%
  \finentry
  \endgroup
  \hrule height 1.25pt\relax
  \itemsep\bibitemsep
  \@itempenalty\@M
  \item\strut
  \@itempenalty\z@
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\nocite{wilde,cicero}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. What about the underline? Do you know how to change its color?

Comment: @davitenio There seems to be a way to do that, yes. Have a look at the edited answer.